# Sails.js single instance of an authenticated user

Tags: node.js, session, express, sails.js

I would like to only allow one instance of a user logged in. If I log in on this computer, and then go to another computer to login, the previous session should be destroyed. How can I do that? How can I access all sessions so I can destroy the right one or ensure that session's userID is unique? The only documentation I've seen for accessing the session regards `req.session`, which is only for the current session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical way to implement this would be to save a user's session ID in the database, and whenever they log in, destroy the session whose ID was previously stored.  Sails uses [Connect's session store](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) for session management.  The session ID is exposed as `req.sessionID`, and the underlying session store is exposed as `req.sessionStore`.  So, given the session store interface described in the Connect docs, you could do something like the following in your login action:

```
// Destroy the session from the previous login
req.sessionStore.destroy(loggedInUser.currentSessionId, function(err) {
    if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
    // Save the session ID of the current login
    User.update({id: loggedInUserId}, {currentSessionId: req.sessionID})
    .exec(function(err) {
        if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
        // Continue your login action...
    });
});
```

Comment: From a performance standpoint, wouldn't it be faster to loop through all the sessions and find a session with the user trying to login? Surely staying in memory(sails built in session store/reddis) would be faster than going through a db that is most likely on persistent storage.

Comment: On second thought, this could be a bad idea. Even though race conditions aren't the issue, having many sessions would slow everyone else down while it's searching since loops are blocking, while a database connection would be non blocking?

Comment: Hard to say.  The only extra db call here is the `User.update`, which you technically don't even have to wait for in order to continue.    The `sessionStore.destroy` is very fast, as it uses a hash indexed by session ID.  If you instead had to loop through all the sessions, and there were a lot of them, it could possibly slow performance (and you would have to wait for it before continuing on).

Comment: Ha, didn't see your second comment there, but that's basically what I was saying ;)

Comment: Any reason for using `User.update` instead of `loggedInUser.currentSessionId = req.sessionID; loggedInUser.save();`? As far as I know, User.update is for updating more than one instance of the model, while save is just for one.

Comment: They're functionally equivalent.  There are currently some issues around using `.save()` on model instances that have their associations populated with `.populate()`, which can be mitigated by calling `.toObject()` on the instance first, but I just default to using `Model.update` in examples.